# linux ldap authentication set gid to uid

Tags: linux, ldap, sssd

I'm setting up ldap authentication with sssd for a linux server. everything works fine. however, the users from the ldap server have a default group User. which is,

uid=10001 (larry), gid= 20001 (User), groups = 20001 (User), 20002 (dev)

I'm wondering is there anyway to override/filter the default User group so it will be something like?

uid=10001 (larry), gid= 10001 (larry), groups = 20002 (dev), which is like default linux user/group,

or

uid=10001 (larry), gid= 20002 (dev), groups = 20002 (dev)

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I know is using `nss_override_attribute_value`. I don't know if this helps for your specific case. Example:

```
nss_override_attribute_value gidNumber 20002
```